# not able to fetch on any field

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I use spring boot, with jpa and hibernate

```
@Entity
@IdClass(SamplesPK.class)
public class Samples{
    ..
    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name = "sampling_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
        @JoinColumn(name = "sampling_year", referencedColumnName = "year")})
    private Samplings sampling;
    ...
}

@Entity
@IdClass(SamplingsPK.class)
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
public class Samplings {
    @OneToOne
    private Products product;
}

@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
public abstract class Products{
    ...
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private ProductTypes productType;
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("TraditionalProducts")
public class TraditionalProducts extends Products {
    ...
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("GranulateProducts")
public class GranulateProducts extends Products  {
     @ManyToMany(mappedBy="granulateProducts")
    private Set<Suppliers> suppliers = new HashSet<>();
}
```

In a repository, I wrote this query

```
 @Query(value = "select s from Samples s Join Fetch s.sampling sp Join Fetch sp.machine m Join Fetch sp.product p Join Fetch p.productType")
 public Page<Samples> findAllFullSample(Pageable pageable);
```

I get this message

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   org.hibernate.QueryException: query specified join fetching, but the
>   owner of the fetched association was not present in the select list
>   [FromElement{explicit,not a collection join,fetch join,fetch non-lazy
>   properties,classAlias=sp,role=com.lcm.model.Samples.sampling,tableName=samplings,tableAlias=samplings1_,origin=samples
>   samples0_,columns={samples0_.sampling_id samples0_.sampling_year
>   ,className=com.lcm.model.Samplings}}] [select count(s) from
>   com.lcm.model.Samples s Inner Join Fetch s.sampling sp Inner Join
>   Fetch sp.machine m Inner Join Fetch sp.product p Inner Join Fetch
>   p.productType]
>
> Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: query specified join
>   fetching, but the owner of the fetched association was not present in
>   the select list [FromElement{explicit,not a collection join,fetch
>   join,fetch non-lazy
>   properties,classAlias=sp,role=com.lcm.model.Samples.sampling,tableName=samplings,tableAlias=samplings1_,origin=samples
>   samples0_,columns={samples0_.sampling_id samples0_.sampling_year
>   ,className=com.lcm.model.Samplings}}] [select count(s) from
>   com.lcm.model.Samples s Inner Join Fetch s.sampling sp Inner Join
>   Fetch sp.machine m Inner Join Fetch sp.product p Inner Join Fetch
>   p.productType]

If I remove all fetch command, it's working, why I can't use fetch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use fetch with paging, but you will need to put a query for count row...

check this post
https://codingexplained.com/coding/java/spring-framework/fetch-query-not-working-spring-data-jpa-pageable#comment-293535